# Using Hapi on an Axis service: "Can't create XML document"

Tags: java, tomcat, axis, hapi

I'm developing an Axis service to interface with a HL7 remote service. I have a class (Hl7MessageTranslator) to encode query request like this:

```
public Hl7MessageTranslator(...)
{
...
parser = new DefaultXMLParser();
}

public String encodeRequest(...) throws ... HL7Exception
{
// prepare HL7 query request
QRY_A19 qryA19 = new QRY_A19();
    ...
    return parser.encode(qryA19);
 }
```

the encodeRequest() method works fine when called outside the tomcat environment (JUnit test) but fails when called from the Axis service:
I get the following warning while creating the class:

```
SLF4J: This version of SLF4J requires log4j version 1.2.12 or later. See also  http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4j_version
INFO - 2014-05-20 09:11:07,543 - Classe: ca.uhn.hl7v2.util.Home - Metodo: setHomeDirectory - Descrizione: hapi.home is set to C:\Programmi\eclipse-j2ee-helios\. 
INFO - 2014-05-20 09:11:07,933 - Classe: ca.uhn.hl7v2.VersionLogger - Metodo: printHapiVersion - Descrizione: HAPI version is: 2.2 
INFO - 2014-05-20 09:11:07,949 - Classe: ca.uhn.hl7v2.VersionLogger - Metodo: checkStructureLibraries - Descrizione: Default Structure libraries found for HL7 versions 2.5, 2.6,  
WARN - 2014-05-20 09:11:08,011 - Classe: ca.uhn.hl7v2.VersionLogger - Metodo: checkDOMImplementation - Descrizione: Error occured while trying to retrieve a DOMImplementation. 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.dom.DOMXSImplementationSourceImpl cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.DOMImplementationSource
at ca.uhn.hl7v2.util.XMLUtils.getDOMImpl(XMLUtils.java:55)
at ca.uhn.hl7v2.VersionLogger.checkDOMImplementation(VersionLogger.java:44)
at ca.uhn.hl7v2.VersionLogger.init(VersionLogger.java:36)
at ca.uhn.hl7v2.DefaultHapiContext.<init>(DefaultHapiContext.java:126)
at ca.uhn.hl7v2.DefaultHapiContext.<init>(DefaultHapiContext.java:112)
at ca.uhn.hl7v2.DefaultHapiContext.<init>(DefaultHapiContext.java:103)
at ca.uhn.hl7v2.parser.Parser.<init>(Parser.java:71)
at ca.uhn.hl7v2.parser.XMLParser.<init>(XMLParser.java:89)
at ca.uhn.hl7v2.parser.DefaultXMLParser.<init>(DefaultXMLParser.java:81)
at com.avelco.integrazioni.areavasta.naar.Hl7MessageTranslator.<init>(Hl7MessageTranslator.java:105)
at com.avelco.integrazioni.areavasta.naar.NaarBridge.requestGrid(NaarBridge.java:135)
at com.avelco.integration.services.Service.requestGrid(Service.java:122)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
...
WARN - 2014-05-20 09:11:08,011 - Classe: ca.uhn.hl7v2.VersionLogger - Metodo: checkDOMImplementation - Descrizione: XML parsing and encoding as well as working with Conformance Profiles will fail.
```

and the following error while calling the parser.encode() method:

```
20/05/2014 09:11:08 : debug: Filling MSH ...
20/05/2014 09:11:08 : debug: Filling QRD ...
20/05/2014 09:11:08 : debug: Filling QRF ...
ca.uhn.hl7v2.HL7Exception: Can't create XML document - java.lang.RuntimeException
at ca.uhn.hl7v2.parser.DefaultXMLParser.encodeDocument(DefaultXMLParser.java:115)
at ca.uhn.hl7v2.parser.XMLParser.doEncode(XMLParser.java:241)
at ca.uhn.hl7v2.parser.Parser.encode(Parser.java:276)
at com.avelco.integrazioni.areavasta.naar.Hl7MessageTranslator.encodeRequest(Hl7MessageTranslator.java:174)
at com.avelco.integrazioni.areavasta.naar.NaarBridge.requestGrid(NaarBridge.java:144)
at com.avelco.integration.services.Service.requestGrid(Service.java:122)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

Since it works when called by JUnit it must be a dependency/configuration problem but I can't figure where to look for it.

Thanks in advance

Massimo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I came out of this.

As Hussein Zawawi suggested it was a jar conflict with axis, only it was *Xerces* and not *log4j* the cause.

It seems that some HAPI `DefaultXMLParser` methods expected `org.w3c.dom` Objects but the factory in my environment produced `org.apache.xerces.dom` ones.

Unfortunately I couldn't remove *Xerces* from the project without breaking the *legacy* software I'm working with. Eventually I had to write my own implementation of `DefaultXMLParser` rewriting *faulty* methods and replacing XML parse and serializing calls.

```
public class AvXmlParser extends DefaultXMLParser
{

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see ca.uhn.hl7v2.parser.DefaultXMLParser#encodeDocument(ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.Message)
 */
public Document encodeDocument(Message source) throws HL7Exception
{
String messageClassName = source.getClass().getName();
String messageName = messageClassName.substring(messageClassName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = null;
try
{
// doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
    doc = XmlUtilities.emptyDom();
// Element root = doc.createElement(messageName);
    Element root = doc.createElementNS("urn:hl7-org:v2xml",messageName);
    doc.appendChild(root);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new HL7Exception("Can't create XML document - " + e.getClass().getName(), e);
}
encode(source, doc.getDocumentElement());
return doc;
}

/**
 * @param groupObject
 * @param groupElement
 * @throws HL7Exception
 */
private void encode(ca.uhn.hl7v2.model.Group groupObject, org.w3c.dom.Element groupElement) throws HL7Exception
{
String[] childNames = groupObject.getNames();
String messageName = groupObject.getMessage().getName();
try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < childNames.length; i++)
    {
    Structure[] reps = groupObject.getAll(childNames[i]);
    for (int j = 0; j < reps.length; j++)
    {
        Element childElement = groupElement.getOwnerDocument().createElement(makeGroupElementName(messageName, childNames[i]));
        groupElement.appendChild(childElement);
        if (reps[j] instanceof Group)
        {
        encode((Group) reps[j], childElement);
        }
        else if (reps[j] instanceof Segment)
        {
        encode((Segment) reps[j], childElement);
        }
    }
    }
}
catch (DOMException e)
{
    throw new HL7Exception("Can't encode group " + groupObject.getClass().getName(), e);
}
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see ca.uhn.hl7v2.parser.XMLParser#parseStringIntoDocument(java.lang.String)
 */
protected synchronized Document parseStringIntoDocument(String message) throws HL7Exception
{
try
{
    Document doc = XmlUtilities.parseString(message);
    return doc;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new HL7Exception("Exception parsing XML",e);
}
}
}
```

(The `XmlUtilities` class is a utility class already available in my environment).
Most of the problems were so because of the legacy software I'm working with and not because of HAPI or Xerces but I hope my solution can be useful in future.

Answer (score 1):

It is a jar conflict issue with axis dependencies. If you have any seperate log4j jar remove it.

Comment: Thanks but ... I tried removing log4j from classpath but it doesen't work. Without log4j the class fails even when called from JUnit.

Comment: The classpath not related to tomcat. you can keep the reference there but make sure you dont move the jar to tomcat webapp

Comment: OK, I'll try this. (My service is part of a proprietary framework so it'll take a while ...)